# Why am I all of a sudden getting a Natbib warning?; all my citations are not working anymore

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm using a LaTex template in Overleaf, I've been using it for months now and the citations always worked as I expected. Now all of a sudden I get a Natbib warning that all of my citations are undefined. My main.txt looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{clv3}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% Packages for template
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{standalone}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=darkblue, linkcolor=darkblue, urlcolor=darkblue}

% Your packages here

\bibliographystyle{compling}

\input{meta-data.tex}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\input{front-page.tex}
\input{thesis.tex}
\end{document}
```

I'm new to working in LaTex and have no clue what I did to make this happen. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

This is the template I'm using (for information about compling style and cvl3): [https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tilburg-university-csai-and-ds-and-s-masters-thesis-template/gybfzfwjmvjf][1]

UPDATE: 
Got in contact with Overleaf. This fixed my problem:

Creating a new file in the root directory called 'latexmkrc' (with no file extension), and inserting into it the following:

$pdflatex = 'pdflatex --shell-escape %O %S; bibtex %R;'

Comment: Please make this example self contained as we do not have access to the files you input. Also are you 100% sure that you do not have any compilation errors.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load packages more than once (cf `standalone`), and do load `hyperref` *last*.

Comment: @daleif I added the template I'm using. Hope this is sufficient.

Comment: No the template is not sufficient. Quite probably you introduced an error somewhere. Check the blg-file and the log-file for errors.

Comment: I don't have any errors. Just this warning for every citation: Package natbib Warning: Citation '3D_explain' on page 9 undefined on input line 227

Comment: Show the content of the blg-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer do you know how to access those on Overleaf? I was looking for the generated `bbl` file with a student earlier today.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I assumed you meant the bibliography file, so I added that. Couldn't find a bgl-file besides log file in overleaf.

Comment: @daleif I asked for the blg not the bbl, but I just run a test project and both are under the "other log and files" section and can be easily downloaded. My output.blg e.g. starts with `This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2018)
`.

Comment: @daleif here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqCyP.png

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks, I hardly ever use overleaf, so I have no idea where things are. Though today I a had a student who hadn't updated her miktex for a long time and from all the oberdiek stuff I at least knew how to update it properly

Comment: @daleif I don't have bgl or bbl under "other log and files". The options I have are aux, chktex, log, out, pdf, qry and syntex.gz.

Comment: I have a similar issue with "\bibliographystyle{abstract}". I suspect these issues have something to do with latest updates on Overleaf. I hope they fix these issues as soon as possible